# AngularJS [$injector:modulerr] error appearing only in remote server, not in local

Tags: angularjs, server

I have a website that uses AngularJS extensively. When testing the website locally using either MAMP or a simple python http server on my machine, everything works fine. However when I deploy the website on a remote server, I get the following AngularJS error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module AppBootstrap due to:
URL does not match any environments
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=AppBootstrap&p1=URL%20does%20not%20match%20any%20environments
```

What could be the issue, that surprisingly doesn't make it break in local?

I have very limited knowledge in AngularJS. I noticed that the exact same error was appearing when I simply opened the main webpage locally without any local server set up.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with `html5Mode` and URL rewrites.  What is the remote server you are deploying to?

Comment: and can you show how the `<script>` tag that is being used for that module (AppBootstrap) looks?

Comment: @Claies Thanks for your help - the remote server is a standard LAMP server (Apache/CentOS).
Everything is contained in a minified js file (unfortunately, I don't have access to the original non-minified file) which is referenced by a single script tag `<script src="js/118e9984.app.min.js"></script>` in my `index.html` file.

Comment: when you say "everything", you mean that one file is every script your site uses?

Comment: This don't make sense? If the *only* script that is referenced is a minified script, how are you getting an un-minified error with a full module name?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this part of the error message, my guess is that you had a conditional setting somewhere that was meant to dynamically make updates based on debug/dev/test/prod environments:

> p1=URL%20does%20not%20match%20any%20environments

I'd either check to see that the URL being used on the remote server matches what is expected in the conditional, or update the module accordingly.